# <optgroup> in Opera using jQuery

Tags: jquery, opera

I'm having an issue with `<optgroup>` in Opera using jQuery.  First, here's the code:

```
// returns a jQuery optgroup object
function getSpaceOptGroup(locationName) {
    var location = locations.first(function(l) {
        return l.name == locationName;
    });

    var optGroup = $("<optgroup label='" + location.name + "'></optgroup>");

    $.each(location.spaces, function(i,x) {
        optGroup.append("<option value='" + x.id + "'>" + x.name + "</option>");
    });

    return optGroup;
}
```

This function returns to a simple `apend()`.  What happens is that only the `<opgroup>` label appears and none of the options, but only in Opera.  It works in FF, Safari, and IE.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This problem doesn't seem to exist in Opera 10, only Opera 9,6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm seeing the same issue using jQuery 1.3 and Opera 9.64 on Linux. If I simply remove the <optgroup> tags, the list magically appears.

Doing a bit of digging, it looks like this is an Opera bug, not a jQuery bug: http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/3040

There is apparently a workaround as well: http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/3040#comment:7

```
// Do not use:
var optGroup = $("<optgroup></optgroup>");
var option = $("<option></option>");
// But:
var optGroup = $(document.createElement("optgroup"));
var option = $(document.createElement("option"));
// Then everything works as expected
optGroup.attr("label", "hello").append(
    option.append("foo"),
    option.clone().text("bar"));
// with append of course
$("select#test5").append(optGroup);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem for the hierselect menu in my [PHP Form Class](http://www.php-ease.com/classes/form.html) and the workaround code given in the answer did not work, but this did:

```
var optGroup = $(document.createElement("optgroup")).attr("label", "hello");
$("select#test5").append(optGroup);
optGroup.append($(document.createElement("option")).val("foo").html("bar"));
```

The optGroup has to be appended to the select menu first, and then the option(s) appended to the optGroup.